# How to fetch data for a column from two tables in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

There are two tables Customer1 and Customer2

Customer1: List the details of the customer

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GuQaHhZ70D0NHGXuW51B5nNZXrSkthmEduHOhwoZmRg/edit#gid=722500260

Customer2: List the updated details of the customer

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GuQaHhZ70D0NHGXuW51B5nNZXrSkthmEduHOhwoZmRg/edit#gid=0

CustomerName has to be fetched from both the tables.If the customer name is updated it has to be fetched from Customer2 table else it has to fetched from Customer1 table.So all customernames should be listed.

Expexted Resultset:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GuQaHhZ70D0NHGXuW51B5nNZXrSkthmEduHOhwoZmRg/edit#gid=1227228207

How this can be achieved in spark scala?

Answer (score 0):

You can perform **`Left Join`** on **customer1** table then using **`coalesce`** on **customer2** table to get **`first non null value`** for `customername` column.

***Example*:**

```
scala> val customer1=Seq((1,"shiva","9994323565"),(2,"Mani","9994323567"),(3,"Sneha","9994323568")).toDF("customerid","customername","contact")
scala> val customer2=Seq((1,"shivamoorthy","9994323565"),(2,"Manikandan","9994323567")).toDF("customerid","customername","contact")
scala> customer1.as("c1")
       .join(customer2.as("c2"),$"c1.customerid" === $"c2.customerid","left")
       .selectExpr("c1.customerid",
            "coalesce(c2.customername,c1.customername) as customername")
       .show()
```

***Result:***

```
+----------+------------+
|customerid|customername|
+----------+------------+
|         1|shivamoorthy|
|         2|  Manikandan|
|         3|       Sneha|
+----------+------------+
```

Comment: I need to get this entry also in the final resultset                                                               3 Sneha 9994323568.                                                                                                                                                                        Expected Resultset: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GuQaHhZ70D0NHGXuW51B5nNZXrSkthmEduHOhwoZmRg/edit#gid=1227228207

Comment: @ChitraP, Did the answer helped? If yes accept the answer to close the thread :)  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work